Can you reference another table in DBT test?
I'm wondering if it's possible to run tests that include another table in DBT.
I tried asking chatgpt, but what it suggested doesn't seem to be working.
Something like this yml:
models:
  - name: a
    description: table A
    docs:
      show: true
    config:
      tags: [test]
    tests:
      - dbt_expectations.expect_table_row_count_to_equal:
          value: 5555
    assertion:
      sql: |
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.a a join schema.b b on b.account_id = a.id
      equals: 12345


the assertion key in YAML doesn't exist in dbt. What are you trying to achieve?

Yes. You can do this in a custom test.

Got the answer from the DBT slack group.
Create a test in tests/generic like so:
{% test multi_model_test(model, column_name, other_model, other_column, id_left, id_right) %}
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SUM({{ model }}.{{ column_name }}) - SUM({{ other_model }}.{{ other_column }}) AS diff
    FROM {{ model }}
    LEFT JOIN {{ other_model }}
        ON {{ model }}.{{ id_left }} = {{ other_model }}.{{ id_right }}
) AS sums
WHERE sum_model != sum_other_model
{% endtest %}

then add it in the model yml:
      - name: total
        tests:
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
              column_type: numeric
          - multi_model_test:
              other_model: transaction
              other_column: amount
              id_left: id
              id_right: registration

